# Drupal: Added new taxonomy term to category, but throws an error when used with a different category

Tags: drupal, taxonomy

I have a bunch of taxonomy term categories each with about seven terms. I went to add another term inside of one of the categories and when I tried to use it, i get an error.

I started doing this...I selected one taxonomy term when creating new content, then saved it and it saved correctly. I edited the content, selected another term, then saved it. Up until the error was thrown.

I found that selecting the new term that I just created, and having selected a term from a different category, throws an error. The error is:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 
Duplicate entry '813' for key 'PRIMARY': INSERT INTO {gmap_taxonomy_node} 
(nid, tid, marker) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, 
:db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2); Array ( 
[:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 813 [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => 812 
[:db_insert_placeholder_2] => Other ) in gmap_taxonomy_node_update()(line 
217 of /var/www/most/public/sites/all/modules/gmap/gmap_taxonomy.module).
```

For instance:

Category foo1        : item 1, item 2, item 3, item 4, item 5.

Category foo2        : item 1, item 2, item 3, item 4, item 5.

Category foo3        : item 1, item 2, item 3, item 4, **NEW item 5.**

When selecting the "**NEW item 5**" with 'foo1' there are no errors.

When selected the "**New item 5**" with "foo2" It throws an error.

If I leave foo2 blank, but select an item from foo1, it does not throw an error.

So there is something wrong with foo2 and the NEW item 5 that I just created.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was simply to delete the new taxonomy term and create it again. Since there was no content associated with the term because of the error, it was easily deleted. If you have content already with the term, and the error is there. I would backup the current content somewhere and reupload it once you delete the term.